# What do the wooden poles with flags on them scattered throughout the world symbolize?

Tags: new-world

I see these poles with flags and markers in the ground around them **all over** the game world:

[image: pole]

Considering how many there are in the game, do they have any significance or are they decorative only?  There isn't anything that I can interact with at them, and I don't recall any quests that utilized them in anyway, but since they are all over the world, I would imagine they have some sort of purpose.